# Exclude style/css-loader from webpack when using ExtractTextPlugin

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using `ExtractTextPlugin` with `webpack` so that our site's CSS is extracted into a typical `.css` file.

According to the bundle stats though, `style-loader` and `css-loader` are apparently included in the final bundle (roughly 7k uncompressed.) It's not a lot of file size but I'd rather not have those libs included if possible. I don't think they're doing anything now that the css is separate.

Is there any way for me to exclude those libs?